# The word for "not well-described by statistics"

Tags: descriptive-statistics, terminology

I used to know this 25-cent word, and I have forgotten it.  It describes a phenomenon where common descriptive statistics like mean and variance misrepresent the individuals or maybe the phenomenon itself. (I don't know because I can't look it up!)  I believe it begins with an e, probably an en- or eu-.  Does it sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Could be any number of things (bias? insufficiency? inefficiency?). It might help if you gave more context, at present this is probably too broad (too many possible answers)

Comment: Unrepresentative or non-representative perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for trying; it's more obscure than bias and the like.  Encastic, euthentical, endostatic, something like that.  "Children's classroom learning should not be reduced to test scores because children's individual educational experiences are . . . .  eunomical . . . . or something."  Looking for this one single specific word, not any word that describes this situation.

Comment: Could it be Exogenous? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exogeny

Answer (score 2):

The word I'd been driving myself crazy to recall was "ergodic" -- "the ensemble average equals the time average" -- with the concept I was trying to research being "nonergodic" meaning a phenomenon dependent on its history.

Comment: Ergodicity is one kind of good behaviour. If anything, it makes statistical treatment easier, and not more difficult.

Comment: Right, @NickCox, nonergodic was the term I ultimately needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sound of the word, maybe idiosyncratic?  If there is idiosyncratic error, then estimating summary statistics just in a cross-section would not be meaningful.